# Getting 'Minimum TLS Version' setting of Azure webapp with Az PowerShell

Tags: azure-powershell

I have a PowerShell script that uses Az PowerShell modules to retrieve properties of all webapps within a resource group. Now, I also need to fetch the `MinTlsVersion` property as in below. Can I do it using one of Az modules?

When a call to `Get-AzWebApp` command is made in the script, a request is sent to `/subscriptions/<s>/resourceGroups/<rg>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites` endpoint. The response object has property `siteConfig` set to `null`. Is there a way to call `Get-AzWebApp` such that the property is not `null` so I can use the `minTlsVersion` sub-property under the `siteConfig` object?

If there's no way to above:

I see that the client receives `minTlsVersion` by sending a GET request to `/subscriptions/<s>/resourceGroups/<rg>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<st>/config/web` endpoint. Can we hit the same endpoint by using one of the Az PowerShell modules? Though, I would prefer a request that can return `minTlsVersion` of all webapps in a resource group in a single call.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it should work. Just that we have more than 1000 webapps so I will try to find a way to batch the requests.

Comment: Anyway, you need to pass the `-Name` parameter, when using/not using the parameter, it calls different APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate through each app, try the command as below, it works on my side.

```
$grouname = "<resource-group-name>"
$apps = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $grouname
$names = $apps.Name
foreach($name in $names){
    $tls = (Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $grouname -Name $name).SiteConfig.MinTlsVersion
    Write-Host "minTlsVersion of web app" $name "is" $tls
}
```

[image]

Comment: and also please let me know how we can restrict or block TLS 1.0,1.1 across all the apps via az command?